# What is the significance of anchorPoint property in SpriteKIT

Tags: sprite-kit

What is the significance of anchorPoint property in SpriteKIT?

I used it to position a specific node above the lower border of the screen. However, is that the only way to make sure that the objects don't cross the lower borders of the screen in a world where gravity is set to true?

What should the anchor point be set to to ensure that a specific node doesn't go out of horizontal/vertical bounds in case an impulse is applied?

Comment: Also see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33099051/how-to-position-child-skspritenodes-inside-their-parents/33099930#33099930

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Sprites/Sprites.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013043-CH9-SW36) on the `anchorPoint`.  Basically, the `anchorPoint` is used to define the center of an object.  By that, I mean when you set the `position` of the node, it sets the position of the node's `anchorPoint` in the scene.  From there, the `anchorPoint` with tell the node (I'm going to use Apple's spaceship example) that the image should be shifted so that the `anchorPoint` is wherever you defined.  `anchorPoint` is a 1.0 by 1.0 size area, with 0.0, 0.0 being the bottom left of the sprite, and 1.0, 1.0 being the top right.  It scales for however wide your sprite is.  When you adjust the `zRotation` of your sprite, it will rotate around the `anchorPoint`.

So if I say, have a sprite with an `anchorPoint` at 0.5, 1.0, and I set the position to the exact center of the screen, the sprite will actually hang down, as the `anchorPoint` has been moved up to the top of the node.

Anyway, it should not have an effect on physics.  I would recommend using `position` for setting the position of the node instead.  If you are looking to make sure a physics body won't go through a wall/`phsyicsBody`, then run `usesPreciseCollisionDetection = YES` (or whatever language you are using's `true` statement) on your node's `physicsBody`.